# Monkey patching in Python using lists

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I need to override functionality in several libraries and would like to programmatically monkey patch the functions by iterating through a list that I specify ahead of time.

The patching works if I set up my code like this:

```
def monkey_patch(method):
    def patch(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Patch!')
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    return patch

def func_a(text):
    print(f'You called func_a with: {text}')
    
func_a('Hello') #  You called func_a with: Hello

original = func_a
func_a = monkey_patch(func_a)
func_a('Hello again') #  Patch!
                      #  You called func_a with: Hello again

func_a = original
func_a('Hello one last time') #  You called func_a with: Hello one last time
```

However, trying to have this driven by a list fails because the assignment thinks I'm trying to assign the function to the container instead of the function that is being pointed to:

```
patch_list = [(func_a, monkey_patch)]
unpatch_list = []

for patch in patch_list:
    original = patch[0]
    patch[0] = patch[1](patch[0]) #  TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
    unpatch_list.append((patch[0], original)) #  Store the original function so the patch can be removed later
    
for patch in unpatch_list:
    patch[0] = patch[1] #  TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there a way to 'dereference' the items in the tuple to allow the list methodology to work?

Comment: I think you fundamentally misunderstand the semantics of assignment. Note, what you are doing isn't really monkeypatching. You are decorating these functions. To do this dynamically, it seems you want to do it *inside* the actual module. So one approach would be to modify `globals()` directly.

Comment: "dereferencing" doesn't make sense in Python, *Python doesn't have pointers*. `original` is refering to the actual function object you are interested in. It is already "dereferenced". Note, you are using `tuple` objects, which *are immutable*. But even if you used list objects, that wouldn't really do what you are trying to do

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga! Globals() is exactly what I needed, it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to juanpa.arrivillaga, here is a way to do this for both decorators and regular monkey patches using globals():

```
def patch_a(method):
    def patch(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Patch 1!')
        return method(*args, *kwargs)
    return patch

def patch_b(text):
    print(f'Patch 2 called with: {text}')

def func_a(text):
    print(f'You called func_a with: {text}')
    
def func_b(text):
    print(f'You called func_b with: {text}')

patch_list = [
    ('func_a', patch_a, True),
    ('func_b', patch_b, False)
             ]
unpatch_list = []

func_a('Hello')  # You called func_a with: Hello
func_b('Hello again')  # You called func_b with: Hello again

for patch in patch_list:
    unpatch_list.append((patch[0], globals()[patch[0]]))
    
    if patch[2]:
        globals()[patch[0]] = patch[1](globals()[patch[0]])
    else:
        globals()[patch[0]] = patch[1]

func_a('Hello')  # Patch 1!
                 # You called func_a with: Hello
func_b('Hello again')  # Patch 2 called with: Hello again

for patch in unpatch_list:
    globals()[patch[0]] = patch[1]

func_a('Hello')  # You called func_a with: Hello
func_b('Hello again')  # You called func_b with: Hello again
```